# Why does it work to connect between phase and ground, if the electrical circuit is not completed or closed?

Tags: ground, grounding, phase

Maybe it's a silly question about electrical installations.

I'm not talking about rules, protections or if it is correct to do what I'm going to describe.

**I just want to understand why it works.**

For example, if I bury a copper rod in the garden of my house, and if I connect to an incandescent lamp by means of a cable connected to the phase of the electrical supply and the other terminal connects to said rod, the lamp works correctly.

My question is how the circuit is completed, the current should return to the other terminal of the source (the neutral). Said source is the secondary of the power supply transformer.

[image]

Comment: FYI What you are describing is a common practice called Single Wire Earth Return (SWER), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return) for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your drawing lacks is that the circuit will be completed by having the transformer side neutral also connected to a metal rod buried to ground.

The moist soil will conduct current between the metal rods.

Likely your house also has a ground rod and that ground wire is connected to neutral. Exact details will vary between countries, electrical code and how your house specifically is wired, but exact details are not needed to explain how the circuit is completed.

Comment: That's what I suspected.

That is to say that if the neutral of the transformer wasn't connected to ground, the lamp would not work. 

Am I correct?

Comment: True, if the transformer neutral is never connected to earth at transformer or at your house or anywhere else then the neutral wire has no path.

Comment: Tnagentially, very rarely in industrial and healthcare installations floating neutrals *are* deliberately used. In this case, if line touches ground nothing will trip and phase become grounded instead of neutral. In this case there is always also a device to set off an urgent alarm. This allows doctors or people running hazardous operations at factories time to do life-saving things with power still going to critical equipment. It also means that faults like shorts to metal cases don't create sparks which can be important, for example, in an explosives factory.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing this:

[image]

The neutral is connected to ground.  The ground is not a good conductor, but with enough contact area (long ground rod,) it is good enough.

Comment: That's what I suspected. That is to say that if the neutral of the transformer wasn't connected to ground, the lamp would not work. Am I correct?

Comment: It might still light up weakly.  Transformers aren't perfect, so some current will leak through.  The power plant (on the other side of the transformer) is most certainly grounded, so with a little leakage through the transformer your light still might glow (dimly.)  It could possibly deliver enough current to zap you.

Comment: "The ground is not a good conductor". Relative to copper, no, it isn't a good conductor. However, a grounding rod can often easily draw 10 A or more when connected to a 120 V Line. -- enough to easily light a lamp. For a fun demonstration of the conductivity of the ground watch https://youtu.be/gHQE5L6hbgs